# How can I cache the results returned by searchkick in rails using low level caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, caching, searchkick

How can I cache the results returned by searchkick in rails using low level caching?
It seems the returned items object is unique on every search, thus busting the cache?

Here is some sample code I'm using.. in my controller

```
cache_key = ["results_controller", @store, @category, @search, @page]
@items = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 1.week) {Searchkick.search(@search...)}
```

I then have a

`@sid = @items.search.id`

down below to track searches.. I believe this search_id is unique per search, thus busting the cache.. how can I cherry pick the attributes returned in the `.search` method so as to preserve the caching?

This is for a multi-model search query.. hence using `Searchkick.search()` instead of `YourModel.search()`

Comment: You keep mentioning busting the cache, and you're talking about what's returned from `Searchkick`, but the `cache_key` is the only thing that's affecting your cache lookup, and you'd not including the search results in that key. Maybe I'm missing something, no idea what `@sid` is, can't see that in your code.

Comment: good point.. the problem was indeed in the cache key itself.. i was using an array (@models) of YourModel.new type models instantiated.. these are always unique so the cache key was always unique.. 

problem was solved after i used a string representation of the models in the cache key

Comment: Still not seeing how what you mention impacts `@store, @category, @search, @page` but glad you got it sorted.

Comment: sorry, `@store` was using `@models` which is a bit indirect but `@models` was composed of a bunch of YourModel.new objects which are brand new every time, thus making a super unique.. I guess the lesson is to inspect cache key properly before assuming fault.